# Order 1,0 for six times so that the 1 appears exactly $4$ times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm calculating this problem:

$A,B$ play against each other. $A$ has the possibility of winning a game of $p$. To win a tournament you have to win $4$ games. What are the chances of $A$ winning the tournament?

My logic is: if in order to win you need $4$ wins, so the tournament is going to be between $4-5-6-7$ games based on results.

- If they play 4 games - so the only option for a to win is $aaaa$.
- If they play 5 games - so $baaaa, abaaa, aabaa, aaaba, aaaab $

If they play 6 games, it's trickier. I would have to calculate how many orders of $a,b$ six times, so that $a$ appears exactly $4$ times, exist. (From here, the title of the question). How do you calculate something like this? Considering I need it also for the $7$?

Comment: The usual idea for this sort of thing is to imagine that all $7$ games are played, regardless of the fact that a winner is probably decided prior to the final game.  It is still true that the winner of the series is the only one who wins at least $4$ games out of the $7$.  And now it is a simple binomial calculation.

Comment: So you're saying to directly calculate all the orders in 7 in which a appears exactly 4 times and that will be enough?

Comment: No, you need to consider the cases in which $a$ wins $\textit {at least}$ $4$ games out of the $7$, not exactly $4$.

Comment: Why though? The winner is the first one to win 4 games. There can't be a combination in which either $a$ or $b$ appear more than $4$ times cause the game would be have been already ended by then. No?

Comment: This is a counting trick that makes the computation a lot easier.  imagine two series are played. Both are best out of seven.  In yours, the series stops once someone has won $4$ games.  In mine, all $7$ are played and the winner is the player who has won at least $7$.  Convince yourself that if I truncate my series at the game where the eventual winner has won game $4$ then I get your series back and that the remainder of the games have no impact on the winner. But it is $\textit {a lot}$ easier to compute it my way.

Comment: If you aren't convinced, do both computations.  The way you sketched in your post is not really all that hard, so just finish it.  Then do it my way and convince yourself that $a.$ you get the same result.  And $b.$ the computation is a lot easier.

Comment: I'm just afraid that by countering all combinations like you say I get also something like $aaaaaab$ which I would not add otherwise.

Comment: The idea is that you get that sequence, but you also get $aaaabbb$ and $aaaabba$ and so on.  Thus you are adding in all possible "tails" after $aaaa$, so there is no harm in them.  But, as I say, it is easy enough to do it both ways and to compare the results.

Comment: To do it the way you started, don't forget that $A$ must win the final game (else the series would already have ended.  Thus, in order for $A$ to win in six games, say, $A$ must win exactly three out of the first five, and then $A$ must win game $6$.

Comment: How is there no harm in them? I mean the number of combinations change no? Also, the following question is "assume they have played all 7 games, what is the answer now?". How would I tackle this answer then?

Comment: Please, just try the computations.  Both methods are very easy.  My way is easier, I feel, because it is a straight forward binomial distribution. Just work out the probability that  $A$ wins exactly $4$, exactly $5$, exactly $6$, or exactly $7$ games.  But your way is only a little bit harder.

Comment: Ok I get it thank you!